# Worker connecting to server but executing on client with multiprocessing package (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

First post here, hello everyone.

I have a problem with the multiprocessing package with python 2.7.
I wish to have some processes run in parallel on a server; they do connect but they are executed locally instead.

This is the code I use on the server (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def server():
    mgr = MyManager(address=("", 2288), authkey="12345")
    mgr.get_server().serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "number of cpus/cores:", cpu_count()

    server = Process(target=server)

    server.start()
    print "server started"

    server.join()
    server.terminate()
```

while this is the code that runs on the client (Mac OS 10.11):

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import current_process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from math import sqrt

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def worker(address, port, authkey):
    mgr = MyManager(address=(address, port), authkey=authkey)
    try:
        mgr.connect()
        print "- {} connected to {}:{}".format(current_process().name, address, port)
    except:
        print "- {} could not connect to server ({}:{})".format(current_process().name, address, port)
    current_process().authkey = authkey
    for k in range(1000000000):
         sqrt(k * k)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create processes
    p = [Process(target=worker, args=("xx.xx.xx.xx", 2288, "12345")) for _ in range(4)]

    # start processes
    for each in p:
        each.start()
    # join the processes
    for each in p:
        each.join()
```

The for loop

```
for k in range(1000000000):
    sqrt(k * k)
```

that's inside the worker function is just to let the workers process a lot, so I can monitor their activity into Activity Monitor or with top.
The problem is that the processes connect (as a matter of fact if I put a wrong address they do not) but they are executed on the local machine, as I see the server CPUs staying idle while the local CPUs going all towards 100%.
Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: You are starting your workers locally, what did you expect? oO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting your `Process` locally on your client. `p` and `for each in p: each.start()` is executed on your client, where it is run and starts the workers.

While each `Process` "connects" to the `Manager` via `mgr.connect()` it never interacts with it. The local `Process`es don't magically transfer to your server just because you opened a connection. Furthermore, a `Manager` isn't meant to run workers, it is [meant to share data](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers).

You'd have to start workers *on the server*, then send work to there.

Comment: As an addition, to communicate you could use multiprocessing Clients and Listeners https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing.connection